# In a nested dataframe, how to calculate only the highest level of categorical variable per unique ID

Tags: r, nested

I have a dataset like this:

```
ID    Action 
id1     A1 
id1     A2 
id1     A2 
id2     A3 
id2     A3 
id3     A1 
....
```

Action is a categorical variable:  A3 > A2 > A1

My question is how can I count only the highest level of Action per distinct ID in R.

To do that, I'm thinking there will be as many Actions as the number of unique IDs.  Each ID would be associated with only one Action -- the highest level. The new dataframe would look like this

```
ID     Action 
ID1    A2 
ID2    A3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we create an ordered factor for `Action` columns, we could take `max` value for each `ID`.

Using base R, we can use

```
aggregate(Action~ID, transform(df, 
          Action = factor(Action, levels = paste0('A', 1:3), ordered = TRUE)), max)

#   ID Action
#1 id1     A2
#2 id2     A3
```

Or in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Action = factor(Action, levels = paste0('A', 1:3), ordered = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Action = max(Action))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("id1", 
"id2", "id3"), class = "factor"), Action = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A1", "A2", "A3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```